# Как устранить скачок большого пальца, во время прокрутки скроллбара?

Tags: c#, winforms

*Подсказка: "большой палец / thumb / скруббер" - это ползунок, расположенный внутри полосы прокрутки. Потянув за который осуществляется прокрутка контента.*

Имеются две полосы прокрутки:

1. **`Пользовательская`**, начинает прокрутку содержимого, только если курсор мыши находится посередине Thumb. Если щелкнуть мышью в другом месте, то Thumb перепрыгнет так, чтобы курсор оказался точно посередине и только тогда начнет прокрутку;
2. **`Стандартная / системная`**, прокручивает содержимое независимо от того, где находится курсор мыши на Thumb.

*Изменение метода "MouseScroll" - дает разные результаты, но прыжок все равно остается*.

**Пользовательский ScrollBar: скачет, когда пытаешься прокручивать НЕ с середины Thumb**

[image]

**Системный ScrollBar: осуществляет прокрутку независимо от того, с какого места тянешь за Thumb.**

[image]

**Beauty_VScrollBar**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    [DefaultEvent("ValueChanged")]
    public class Beauty_VScrollBar : Control {
        #region Setting the initial parameters
        public Beauty_VScrollBar() {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint
                | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true); UpdateStyles();

            Size = new Size(12, 250); Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Basic properties
        private int _value;
        public int Value {
            get { return _value; }
            set {
                _value = value;

                if (Value < Minimum) { Value = Minimum; }
                if (Value > Maximum) { Value = Maximum; }

                Refresh(); OnScroll();
            }
        }

        private int minimum;
        public int Minimum {
            get { return minimum; }
            set { minimum = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        private int maximum = 100;
        public int Maximum {
            get { return maximum; }
            set { maximum = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public int SmallStep { get; set; } = 1;

        [Browsable(false)]
        public enum ScrollOrientation {
            Horizontal = 0x114, Vertical = 0x115
        }

        private ScrollOrientation orientation;
        public ScrollOrientation Orientation {
            get { return orientation; }
            set { orientation = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties responsible for design
        [Description("Thumb size")]
        private int thumbSize = 50;
        public int ThumbSize {
            get { return thumbSize; }
            set { thumbSize = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        [Description("Thumb color")]
        private Color thumbColor = Color.Gray;
        public Color ThumbColor {
            get { return thumbColor; }
            set { thumbColor = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        [Description("Scroll bar fill color")]
        private Color backgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
        public Color BackgroundColor {
            get { return backgroundColor; }
            set { backgroundColor = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        [Description("Scroll bar borders color")]
        private Color borderColor = Color.Silver;
        public Color BorderColor {
            get { return borderColor; }
            set { borderColor = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Key Events
        public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
        #endregion

        #region Event handlers
        private Rectangle thumbRect;
        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left
                && !thumbRect.Contains(e.Location)) MouseScroll(e);

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && thumbRect.Contains(e.Location)) {
                thumbColor = Color.Green; Invalidate();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e) {
            thumbColor = Color.Gray; Invalidate();
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
            thumbColor = thumbRect.Contains(e.Location)
                ? thumbColor = Color.Orange : thumbColor = Color.Gray;

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
                thumbColor = Color.Green;
                MouseScroll(e);
            }

            Invalidate();
        }

        private void MouseScroll(MouseEventArgs e) {
            Value = Maximum * (e.Y - thumbSize / 2) / (Height - thumbSize) + 1;
        }

        public virtual void OnScroll(ScrollEventType type = ScrollEventType.ThumbPosition) {
            ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Drawing controls
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
            thumbRect = new Rectangle(2, (Value * (Height - ThumbSize) / Maximum), Width - 4, thumbSize);

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackgroundColor), new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height)); // scroll bar fill
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(ThumbColor), thumbRect); // thumb fill
            
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1)); // drawing the scroll bar borders
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: `Пользовательский ScrollBar: скачет, когда пытаешься прокручивать НЕ с середины Thumb` ... `MouseScroll(MouseEventArgs)` вы сами ориентируетесь на координаты мыши, вот и получаете такой результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Полезные материалы:*

1. Описание ScrollBar: https://webinmind.ru/html/customization-scrollbar-webkit
2. Написание Custom ScrollBar: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14801/How-to-skin-scrollbars-for-Panels-in-C

**Детальная схема полосы прокрутки (ScrollBar)**
[image]

**Код, который позволяет двигать ползунок полосы прокрутки с любого места**

```
private Rectangle thumbRect;

private bool isThumbDown = false;
private bool isThumbDragging = false;

private int oldThumbTop, newThumbTop;
private Point startMouseClickPosition;

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
    // При клике по ScrollBar, отцентрировать Thumb относительно курсора мыши
    if (!thumbRect.Contains(e.Location))
        Value = Maximum * (e.Y - ThumbSize / 2) / (Height - ThumbSize) + 1;

    if (thumbRect.Contains(e.Location)) {
        startMouseClickPosition.Y = (e.Y - thumbRect.Top);
        isThumbDown = true;
    }
}

protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e) {
    isThumbDown = false; isThumbDragging = false;
}

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (isThumbDown) isThumbDragging = true;
    if (isThumbDragging) MoveThumb(e);
}

private void MoveThumb(MouseEventArgs e) {
    int trackPiece = Height - ThumbSize;

    if (isThumbDown && Maximum > 0) {
        newThumbTop = e.Y - startMouseClickPosition.Y;

        if (newThumbTop < 0) {
            oldThumbTop = newThumbTop = 0;
        } else if (newThumbTop > trackPiece) {
            oldThumbTop = newThumbTop = trackPiece;
        } else {
            oldThumbTop = newThumbTop;
        }

        float percent = (float)oldThumbTop / (float)trackPiece;
        float newValue = percent * (Maximum - SmallStep);

        Value = (int)newValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**ОБЪЯСНЕНИЕ ПРОБЛЕМЫ:**

Метод `MouseScroll` делает так, что середина вашего скролбала оказывается в месте клика мыши

```
private void MouseScroll(MouseEventArgs e) {
    Value = Maximum * (e.Y - thumbSize / 2) / (Height - thumbSize) + 1;
}
```

Давайте предположем, что наш скролбал имеет длину `5` пикселей и его `Value = 3`, вся полоска - `9` пикселей. После этого мы кликаем на `4й` (считая с нуля) пиксель. Вот наглядно что происходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот метод, вроде как, правильно используется в `OnMouseDown`, так как тут, если происходит клик вне скролбара, то скролбар "прибегает к мышке":

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left
        && !thumbRect.Contains(e.Location)) MouseScroll(e);
    ....
}
```

А вот в методе `OnMouseMove`, который происходит когда мышка двигается и 100% мышка находится в зоне скролбара, такой метод уже делает не то, что хотелось бы.

**РЕШЕНИЕ ПРОБЛЕМЫ:**

Чтобы решить вашу проблему нужно вне методов создать переменную `private Point startMouseClickPosition` и сохранить туда `e.Location` в методе `OnMouseDown`:

```
private Point startMouseClickPosition;

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
    startMouseClickPosition = e.Location;
    ....
}
```

После этого в методе `OnMouseMove` достаточно просто сместить `Value` на разницу между `e.Location.Y` и `startMouseClickPosition.Y` (не забывая про максимум):

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
    ....
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        thumbColor = Color.Green;
        //MouseScroll(e);
        var newValue = Value + (e.Location.Y - startMouseClickPosition.Y);
        Value = newValue > Maximum ? Maximum : newValue;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Решение, что вы предложили, почти работает, как надо. Если заменить строку "var newValue = Value + (e.Location.Y - startMouseClickPosition.Y);" на "var  newValue = (e.Y - startMouseClickPosition.Y);", то удается схватиться за ползунок с любой стороны и выполнить прокрутку. Но когда ползунок находится далеко от начальной позиции и пытаешься за него схватиться и потянуть, то он возвращается на самый верх. ПОЧЕМУ?

Comment: @Tatami если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его. Если у вас появился новый вопрос, вы можете задать его отдельно.

Comment: @Tatami попробуйте в событии `OnMouseUp` написать `startMouseClickPosition = Value`

Comment: @KuzCode, ваше решение (в событии OnMouseUp написать startMouseClickPosition = Value) не работает.

Comment: @Tatami лучше бы использовали WPF и не морочили себе голову. Там то что вам надо делается легко и просто. Winforms - это не про красивые интерфейсы.

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант, который работает без доп. полей (isThumbDown и isThumbDragging):**

```
private Rectangle thumbRect;

private int oldThumbTop, newThumbTop;
private Point startMouseClickPosition;

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
    // When clicking on the ScrollBar, center the Thumb relative to the mouse cursor
    if (!thumbRect.Contains(e.Location))
        Value = Maximum * (e.Y - ThumbSize / 2) / (Height - ThumbSize) + 1;

    if (thumbRect.Contains(e.Location)) {
        startMouseClickPosition.Y = (e.Y - thumbRect.Top);
        ThumbBackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}

protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e) {
    ThumbBackColor = Color.Gray;
}

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
    ThumbBackColor = thumbRect.Contains(e.Location)
        ? ThumbBackColor = Color.Orange : ThumbBackColor = Color.Gray;

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        ThumbBackColor = Color.Green; MoveThumb(e);
    }
}

private void MoveThumb(MouseEventArgs e) {
    int trackPiece = Height - ThumbSize;

    if (Maximum > 0) {
        newThumbTop = e.Y - startMouseClickPosition.Y;

        if (newThumbTop < 0) {
            oldThumbTop = newThumbTop = 0;
        } else if (newThumbTop > trackPiece) {
            oldThumbTop = newThumbTop = trackPiece;
        } else {
            oldThumbTop = newThumbTop;
        }

        float percent = (float)oldThumbTop / (float)trackPiece;
        float newValue = percent * (Maximum - SmallStep);

        Value = (int)newValue;
    }
}
```